# Python modules import fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I checked similar questions, but nothing really answered my issue.
Similar to another post, my package structure is:

```
mypackage/  
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
    utils/ 
        __init__.py
        common.py
        myutils1.py
    data_classes/ 
        __init__.py
        command_file.py
        myclass.py
```

I need to use this package in multiple ways:
1) import the package and use it in larger scripts
2) run some modules as standalone (eg: python3 myutils1.py )

myutils uses functions from common, to do so, I tried to have

A)

```
from PySfmc.utils import common #directly in myutils.py
```

B)

```
from mypackage import utils         # in __init__.py
from mypackage.utils import common # in myutils.py
```

C)

```
 import common #directly in myutils.py
```

etc

Long story short... I didn't manage to have something that succesfully imports both when importing in the package at the repl  AND when running python3 myutils.py

anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!

---

edit, I guess what it boils down to is that:
from repl I can do either of these:

```
from mypackage.folder.file import function
from mypackage.folder import file
from mypackage import folder
```

but if I write the same inside myutils1.py it will fail

---

edit2:

I edited setup.py from the following line:

`packages=['mypackage'],`

to

`packages=['mypackage','mypackage.data_classes','mypackage.utils']`

this seems to fix my problem: now everything works including the imports that were failing before.

is there any good reason why I should not do this? it seems less hacky than other suggested solutions.

Comment: I guess that "mypackage" is actually "PySfmc"? The second line in B) mentions a "ySfmc", a typo I guess?

Comment: Thank you Michael, well spotted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, scripts are not located within the package itself but in a distinct directory (most often named "bin") at the same level as the project package directory itself, ie:

```
myproject/
    bin/
        myutils1.py
        otherscript.py
    mypackage/  
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
        utils/ 
            __init__.py
            common.py
        data_classes/ 
            __init__.py
            command_file.py
            myclass.py
```

This way the script only use absolute imports (`from mypackage.somemodule import whatever`), and relies on `mypackage` being available in `sys.path` - which is done by [making your package properly installable](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and [allows you to have the scripts installed somewhere in your PATH](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html).

This of course only works properly with a proper install - if you try to run `python bin/myutils1.py` from within `myproject`, the package won't still be found. This can be solved by inserting the proper path (the path to `myproject` at the beginning of `sys.path`:

```
#  bin/myutils1.py
import sys
import os
__PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if __PROJECT_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, __PROJECT_DIR)

from mypackage.utils import common
```

But you only want to do this if you're not planning on doing a properly installable package (if your package is properly installed messing with `sys.path` is not only useless but even possibly harmful) - and then, it's even simpler to just move your scripts directly at the top of your project dir (just **above** your package dir) so the python runtime will already have set `sys.path` correctly:

```
myproject/
    myutils1.py
    otherscript.py
    mypackage/  
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
        utils/ 
            __init__.py
            common.py
        data_classes/ 
            __init__.py
            command_file.py
            myclass.py
```

Comment: Thank you bruno desthuilliers, this was super informative!!
what if I plan to use the package in both ways? both properly installable (and usable from other packages) AND I also would like to run it  with python myutils1.py ? 
is this just bad practice, or there's a 'pythonic' way of doing it?

Comment: Well, if it's installable, you just have to install it to make the package available in sys.path, which already solves the issue.  Note that for development, you can make an "editable" install (it's just al flag at install time).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your package standalone, you need to create a starter outside the package.

```
starter.py
mypackage/  
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
    utils/ 
        __init__.py
        common.py
        myutils1.py
    data_classes/ 
        __init__.py
        command_file.py
        myclass.py
```

starter.py should have this Code:

```
import mypackage.utils.myutils.py
```

If you run starter.py, it will work.

You can find a real world example [in one of my programs](https://gitlab.com/JakobDev/jdTextEdit). This program can be run directly with running jdTextEdit.py, which just imports the jdTextEdit package and it can be installed as module with the setup.py too. I hope, this is whaz yopu are looking for.

Comment: Thank you heaps JakobDev,  this is helpful.
looking into your code I also do not see something like:
```
from jdTextEdit.gui import SettingsWindow   #SettingsWindow is a file, gui a folder
```

is almost like you cannot import a file if it is inside a folder?

Comment: You can Import a file with e.g. Import gui.SettingsWindow in this case. I just prefer the from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it as a package and as a standalone module, you can add this to `myutils.py`, it's hacky but it will work:

```py
import os
import sys
_package_path = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(
        os.path.abspath(__file__)
    )
)
sys.path.insert(0, _package_path)
```

In `myutils1.py` you can import `a_function` from `common.py` like this:

```
from utils.common import a_function
```

In `mymodule.py` you can import `b_function` from `myutils1.py` like this:

```
from utils.myutils1 import b_function
```