# Python import different results from different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I have 2 **identical** files: 
`a.py` and `b.py`  .

they both contain the line

`from mypackage.utils import common`

I also have a package:

```
mypackage/  
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
    utils/ 
        __init__.py
        common.py
        myutils1.py
        b.py
    data_classes/ 
        __init__.py
        command_file.py
        myclass.py
```

I preliminarly do a 
`pip install mypackage`

Then I run:
`python a.py`
which succeeds

and then I run 
`python b.py` (note that b.py is a file within mypackage)

b.py fails with `no module named utils`

Any ideas?

*(note: I am fairly new to stackoverflow, this is not really related to 
[Python modules import fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628641/python-modules-import-fails) , although somehow a followup question, so if I am doing something wrong by asking on a new question please let me know :)*

---

edit:

I install mypackage (and specifically the file b within mypackage) in:

$HOME\github\mypackage\mypackage\utils\b.py

I copy b.py to a.py in:
$HOME\github\mypackage
this works

I copy b.py to a.py in:
$HOME\github\
this doesn't work

so this somewhat explains this... although I still don't know how to fix it!

---

edit:
I edited setup.py from the following line:

`packages=['mypackage'],`

to

`packages=['mypackage','mypackage.data_classes','mypackage.utils']`

this seems to fix my problem: now everything works.

is there any good reason why I should not do this?

Comment: Could you add the path from where you run `python a.py` and `python b.py`?

Comment: Thanks JRajan, I realized that was a hint more than a question :D

I edited my question to reflect what you said there... I still don't understand how I can fix this tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found a couple of solutions to this:

```
import common
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..\\..") # relative path to mypackage, check the slash if you're on linux
from mypackage.utils import common
```

some questions:

why are you moving b.py?

have you installed your package?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Python doesn't know where to find your package in the first place. In the first explain, it looks at the current directory and is able to understand that it is a module, thanks to your `__init__.py` file. So it is able to search for your utils.

In the 2nd example, there is no `__init__.py` file in the current directory and so Python doesn't know where to search for the modules.

The `PYTHONPATH` variable tells Python the directories/modules to search for accessed methods/packages.

So in your case, if you can add your current directory to the `PYTHONPATH` like `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)` while in "$HOME\github\", that should help resolve your issue.

P.S: The OP wants to use the installed package instead of the local module. This solution is applicable when your local modules are not visible for the Python interpreter. For more details, check the comments below.

Comment: sorry... not 100% clear ////  so what you are saying is that it doesn't matter if I install mypackage before running b.py (or a.py in the "wrong" folder) ? ////
it is like when I run them the system is unaware of what packages I installed?

Comment: If you are trying to use the installed package, then my solution is not correct for you. Instead of manually specifying the packages, you could use `setuptools.find_packages()`.

Answer (score 0):

I edited setup.py from the following line:

`packages=['mypackage'],`

to

`packages=['mypackage','mypackage.data_classes','mypackage.utils']`

this seems to fix my problem: now everything works.

is there any good reason why I should not do this?

Comment: This is ok, the only different way is by using [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html); as you can see one of his key features is exactly _"Automatically include all packages in your source tree, without listing them individually in setup.py"_